# why simple_form hidden_field_tag value will not be saved rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, simple-form

im trying to saved an foreign-key into the db with rails
Why is the db column empty at this position and how can i solve this

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :list_id %>
...
<%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn-primary" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use just the attribute name, without the id suffix.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :list %>
```

A better practice is to use [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), imagine you have an **item** resource that belongs to a **list** resource, your route could be like that:

```
POST /lists/1/items
```

It will create a new item to the list id 1, and you don't have to worry about pass the list id as a form field.

I advise you to use [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) gem to make it even easier.

Comment: Thanks but the :list without id dosn't work
How do i create such routes this sounds good is on my todo for the next weeks

Comment: Take a look at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for nested routes. Do you have this code on Github? Can you share with me? My Github account is nicolasiensen.

Comment: Can you stay at this theme, we have to return to it because there are some other issues to do like this->. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462391/how-can-i-get-data-from-an-different-model-then-actionmailer